# How to make value in a column to look back at previous values?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner, so I probably don't use the correct terms when explaining my problem. Hope you can help me anyway.

I have a table consisting of EP.Detect (Movement in entrance), LP.Detect (movement in room), R.Detect (the door can etiher be "open" or "closed" or "moved") and presence is 0 (false) or 1 (true).

The purpose with this is to know when a person is present. And I have done that by making some conditions. My code works fine, except when it come to "closed".

My problem is that it doesn't understand that when R.Detect is closed and EP.Detect and LP.Detect is TimeOut, it doesn't mean that Presence is 0. Because the door haven't been open or moved, therefore the person is still present.

```
  occupied=FALSE    
        j<-1  
        i<-1  
        startRow=1  
        endRow=1  
        n=1  
        for (n in 1:length(dft1$Time)){  
          endRow=n  
        if(dft1$R.Detect[n]=="moved" |dft1$R.Detect[n]=="open" | dft1$R.Detect[n]=="closed"){  

            if(n>1){
              for(i in startRow:endRow){
                if(dft1$R.Detect[n]=="moved" | dft1$R.Detect[n]=="open" ){occupied=TRUE}
                if(dft1$EP.Detect[i]=="Movement" & dft1$LP.Detect[i]=="Movement"){occupied=TRUE}
                if(dft1$EP.Detect[i]=="TimeOut" & dft1$LP.Detect[i]=="Movement"){occupied=TRUE}  
                if(dft1$EP.Detect[i]=="Movement" & dft1$LP.Detect[i]=="TimeOut"){occupied=TRUE}
              }
            }
            for(j in startRow:endRow){dft1$Presence[j]<-occupied}
          }
          startRow=endRow  
          n=n+1  
          occupied=FALSE  
        }
```

[Tried to upload it as a .txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/34htieheyn5b1sq/mydata.txt?dl=0)
[It is easier to understand when you look in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPvWJ.jpg)

```
structure(list(EP.Detect = c("TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"Movement", "Movement", "Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", 
"Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", 
"Movement", "Movement", "Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", "Movement", "Movement", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", "Movement", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", "Movement", 
"Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", 
"Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", "Movement", "Movement", 
"Movement", "Movement", "TimeOut", "Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut"), LP.Detect = c("TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", 
"Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", "Movement", "Movement", 
"Movement", "Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "Movement", "Movement", "Movement", "Movement", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", 
"TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "Movement", 
"Movement", "Movement", "Movement", "TimeOut", "Movement", "Movement", 
"Movement", "Movement", "Movement", "TimeOut", "TimeOut", "TimeOut"
), R.Detect = c("closed", "closed", "open", "moved", "moved", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "moved", "moved", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "moved", "moved", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "moved", 
"moved", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "moved", "moved", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"moved", "moved", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "moved", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "closed", "closed", "open", "closed", "closed", "closed", 
"closed", "moved", "closed", "closed", "closed"), Presence = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("EP.Detect", "LP.Detect", 
"R.Detect", "Presence"), row.names = 25550:25727, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you post the data in text format instead of a picture? In that way it will be easier to reproduce your code and make suggestions. You can do that by using `dput(dft1)` or if your data is too big you can do `head(dput(dft1))`

Comment: I have tried to upload it as .txt. I dont know where to do the dput(dft1) or head(dput(dft1)) ://

Comment: `dput()` is an R function

Comment: you don't need to upload the txt file, rather just copy few lines of the data in you original post in text format, or you run the above code in R and share with us the output (if not too big)

Comment: Wuuhu finally hahah

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to accomplish this much more cleanly with a dplyr case statement without having to use any for loops.

```
library(dplyr)

dft1 <- dft1 %>%
        mutate(Presence = case_when(# If R.Detect is "moved" or "open" or "closed"
                                    # AND (   (EP.Detect on previous row is "Movement" AND LP.Detect on previous row is "Movement" or "TimeOut)
                                    #      OR (EP.Detect on previous row is "TimeOut" AND LP.Detect on previous row is "Movement")
                                    #     )
                                    # THEN set Presence to 1
                                    .$R.Detect %in% c("moved","open", "closed")
                                    & (  (lag(.$EP.Detect) == "Movement" & lag(.$LP.Detect) %in% c("Movement","TimeOut"))
                                       | (lag(.$EP.Detect) == "TimeOut" & lag(.$LP.Detect) == "Movement")
                                      ) ~ 1, 
                                    # All other cases, set Presence to 0
                                    TRUE ~ 0 
                                   )
              )
```

If you do have to process this through a for loop for a particular reason, then this simplified loop should get you what you need

```
# Loop through all rows in the dataframe starting at row 2
for(i in 2:nrow(dft1)){
  # If R.Detect is either "moved", "open", or "closed"
  # AND (   (EP.Detect on the previous row is "Movement" AND LP.Detect on the previous row is either "Movement" or "Timeout")
  #      OR (EP.Detect on the previous row is "TimeOut" AND LP.Detect on the previous row is "Movement")
  #     )
  # Then set Presence to 1
  # Else set Presence to 0
  if(dft1$R.Detect[i] %in% c("moved","open","closed")
     & (  (dft1$EP.Detect[i - 1] == "Movement" & dft1$LP.Detect[i - 1] %in% c("Movement","TimeOut") )
        | (dft1$EP.Detect[i - 1] == "TimeOut" & dft1$LP.Detect[i - 1] == "Movement")
       )
  ){
    dft1$Presence[i] <- 1
  } else{
    dft1$Presence[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh yea.. it definitely look better than mine ... 
but could u maybe explain the last code more? I am not sure why u have c("Movement","TimeOut") for only the first one..?

Comment: Sorry, that was actually a mistake on my part. I had mixed up the EP and LP variables. I've updated the answer to correct that, and added some descriptive comments.

Comment: Thxxx a loot! That makes more sense for me now :D